# jQuery: selector question (closest)

Tags: jquery, selector, closest

i'm having this markup:

```
<div class=gui>
    <div class=form>
        <div class=textbox></div>
        <div class=textbox></div>
        <div class=textbox></div>
        <div class=selectbox></div>
        <div class=selectbox></div>
        <div class=button></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what i want to do is iterate the divs and find their corresponding parents.
like:

textboxes > form

selectbox > form

button > form

form > gui

here's my jQuery selector:

```
var dParent = div.closest("div.form, div.gui");
```

it works nice for the text- and selectboxes, but not for the form.
the strange thing is that the form reports itself as parent instead of the gui.

any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks

Comment: unfortunately i can't use parent because of wrapper divs and such ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.closest()` will select the calling element if it matches the selector, so when you call `$('.form').closest('.form, .gui')` it will return itself `.form` as being the closest.  Therefore, you simply want to call closest from the `.parent()`:

```
var dParent = div.parent().closest("div.form, div.gui");
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/znHUN/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var parent = div.hasClass('form') ? div.closest('.gui') : div.closest('.form');
```

Would be my best guess not knowing anything else about the structure.

Answer (score 0):

[Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest) works by starting with the current element and traversing up the tree until it finds an element matching the selector. When you start with the form, the form itself matches the selector so it is chosen.  Since all you want to do is find the parent, the appropriate method to use is [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents) with a selector:

```
  div.parents('.form:first,.gui:first');
```

Used like:

```
  div.each( function() {
      alert( $(this).attr('class')
                + ' has parent '
                + $(this).parents('.form:first,.gui:first')
                         .attr('class')
      );
  });
```

See example in action at:  http://jsfiddle.net/tFqLE/